# Macro VA_ARGS to VS2010 VC

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, macros, gnu

In GNU-GCC with Linux this is working
`#define sprintfc(string, ...) sprintf(string+strlen(string), ##__VA_ARGS__)`
Is there definition with same effect for Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Visual C compiler [does support variadic macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177415%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). However, the problem is [the GCC extension ##](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Variadic-Macros.html), which removes the leading comma if no arguments are passed.

Because sprintf() is never called without a second argument, your code should work fine if you just remove the ##.